# JDO Exception in google app engine transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am getting the following exception while trying to use transation in app engine datastore.

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Transaction is still active.
You should always close your transactions correctly using commit() or rollback().

FailedObject:org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManager@12bbe6b
at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.close(JDOPersistenceManager.java:277)
```

The following is the code snippet I used :

```
List<String> friendIds = getFriends(userId);
Date currentDate = new Date();
PersistenceManager manager = pmfInstance.getPersistenceManager();
try {
   Transaction trans = manager.currentTransaction();
   trans.begin();
   for(String friendId : friendIds) {
      User user = manager.getObjectById(User.class, friendId);
      if(user != null) {
         user.setRecoCount(user.getRecoCount() + 1);
         user.setUpdatedDate(currentDate);
         manager.makePersistent(user);
      }
   }
   trans.commit();
} finally {
   manager.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

and if the commit or makePersistent fails where is the call to "rollback" ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this - if you declare your transaction inside the try block and close the pm in the finally. You won't get this message if you move your

Transaction trans = manager.currentTransaction();
trans.begin();

to above the try { } section like this:

PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
tx.begin();
 try {
//do my thing
 tx.commit();
}
} catch (Exception e) {
   tx.rollback();
} finally {
   pm.close();
}

javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Transaction is still active. You should always close your transactions correctly using commit() or rollback().

Answer (score 0):

I think the different 'User' object are not belonging to the same Entity Group. All datastore operations in a transaction must operate on entities in the same entity group.

You may begin the transaction inside the loop , so you will be operating on one entity at a time, or make sure all your objects are in the same group.